# What are the differences between delta rule and generalized delta rule?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, algorithms

I know that the delta rule is a gradient decent learning rule. But, what are the differences between these two delta rules? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken the generalised delta rule refers to the backpropagation algorithm, which is basically an extension of the delta rule to deal with hidden layers.

Have a look at the paper "Learning internal representations by error propagation" by Rumelhart, Hinton, and Williams for details.